# Embed Google Text to Speech

Tags: php, html, web, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Is there any Way to include the Google-translate Text-to-Speech to my Web-Page?
(`http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20Stack%20Overflow`)

And the more important question: Is this even allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official API for Google TTS. However many users use the same url, you've provided in the question. This is however limited to 100 characters.

You may also want to take a look at https://github.com/hiddentao/google-tts